# date parsing in java throws exception

Tags: java, parsing, exception, date

Why is the following code throws ParseException?

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
String date = "Jan 1, 2011"; 
df.parse(date);
```

Result:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Jan 1, 2011"

Comment: are you sure? seems okay to me. should work.

Comment: It works for me though, Java 1.6.0_30

Comment: Try this:
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.US);

Comment: double check, that the spaces in your (original) input Strings are real spaces (`0x20`) and not (`0xA0`) (Ref.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184678/why-does-parsing-this-date-string-throw-an-unparseable-date-exception - comments to accepted answer)

Comment: It's likely an issue of your locale, as the constructor you used then calls another constructor with the default locale. Making the locale explicit as Gijs' comment says will likely fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's related with the Locale parameter as @Gijs Overvliet mentioned.
For instance, I'm using Turkish locale and my String should be set accordingly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{
   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
   String date = "Oca 1, 2011"; 
   df.parse(date);
}
```